# How to get the "perfume" smell out of Buckwheat Groats?

Tags: buckwheat

I bought toasted buckwheat groats from Russia, cooked it, and it had a great nutty smell and was delicious.

Now, I can't get Russian ones, so I bought toasted buckwheat groats from American and Canadian sources. They look identical to the Russian ones, but have a nasty perfume-like smell which makes them almost inedible.

Incidentally, the perfume-like American groats are much less firm when cooked. If I'm not careful they turn into wallpaper paste. This never happened with the Russian buckwheat, even when I added too much water or cooked it too long.

Is this just another species, or is there some way to prep the buckwheat beforehand that the Russian company did that I don't know about?

Comment: I've used American groats any number of times to make kasha, and I've never encountered the "perfume" smell you're talking about.  Maybe you should look for a different source or brand?